# How to delete custom domains from Azure AD

Tags: active-directory, azure

I'm trying to register a custom domain in my Azure Active Directory, but, when I try to verify this domain, it says that my domain already been using by another Azure AD or Office 365.

We do not have Office 365 and there's only one AD in Azure.

I tryed to run the "Get-AzureAdDomainNameReference" in Azure Cli logged as a Global Admin user to discover the references pointing to my domain, but I receive this error:

> Get-AzureADDomainNameReference: Error occurred while executing GetDomainNameReferences
>   Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
>   Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
>   RequestId: 6d04656f-ece1-494e-a78d-e06eaaf6a692
>   DateTimeStamp: Sat, 23 May 2020 15:52:12 GMT
>   HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
>   HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
>   HttpResponseStatus: Completed

I want to delete all references to this domain, to register it in my Azure AD from scratch. How can I do this?

Comment: If your domain was already registered to this tenant you would get a different error. This indicates that it is registered to a different AAD tenant. Could someone else have used this domain name with AAD?

Comment: When I tryed to verify my domain, I noted that there was another TXT entry in my DNS, with the same pattern. Maybe, verifying the domain to another AAD. Maybe an AAD under control of an old employee. Is there a way to take control over this?

Comment: If there is already a TXT entry for verify this domain then I would strongly suspect it is already being used in another AAD instance. You would need to speak to Microsoft support to see about retaining ownership of this.